# not equal to expression in Meteor template

Tags: node.js, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts, meteor-helper

I am new to Meteor.How can I write if not equal to expression in Meteor template.
I tried following

```
{{#if currentUser isFalse}}
    <li><a href="{{pathFor 'loginSubmit'}}">Login</a></li>
{{/if}}

{{#if !currentUser}}
   <li><a href="{{pathFor 'loginSubmit'}}">Login</a></li>
{{/if}}

{{#!if currentUser}}
      <li><a href="{{pathFor 'loginSubmit'}}">Login</a></li>
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
{{#unless currentUser}}
      <li><a href="{{pathFor 'loginSubmit'}}">Login</a></li>
{{/unless}}
```

Comment: Great it worked :) Where can I found better doc for this kind of stuffs?

Comment: I found the doc here https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/spacebars#ifunless

Comment: Yeah it is spacebars inspired from handlebars, you can check for handlebars docs too